# Prevent socket.io from creating new connections on emit

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

This question has been asked a few times by others but wasn't answered, so I am going to rephrase to make the issue more clear.
I am trying to have a socket.io application that creates a new client object when a user joins after a button press, then removes it from an entity array when the user either clicks a leave button or disconnects. When testing removing a user by their socket id I stumbled across the fact that a new socket is created every single time an emit case was called from the client.
Here are my js functions that run when the buttons are pressed:

```
// send join request
function joinlobby(room) {
  let socket = io();
  socket.emit("userJoined", room);
}
// emit when a player leaves
function leavelobby(room) {
  let socket = io();
  socket.emit("userLeft", room);
}
```

and here is my node server:

```
// setup server and ports
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// initialize player counts on each server
let players = [0, 0, 0, 0];

//initialize an empty array of entities
let entities = [];

// listen and log when a client connects
server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening at port ' + port);
});

// find our files
app.use(express.static('public'));


// the entity class
class Entity {
  // set if it is bound to a client then get the lobby and the type of entity it is
  constructor(client = null, lobby = 0, type = "t") {
    this.client = client;
    this.lobby = lobby;
    this.type = type;
  }
}

// when a client connects
io.on("connection", socket => {

  // when a client joins a room let us know
  socket.on("userJoined", room => {
    // create a room object for the joined client and take note
    players[room]++;
    let e = new Entity(socket.id, room, "t");
    entities.push(e);
    console.log("Room join. ID: " + socket.id + " - Entities now: " + entities.length + " - Room: " + room);
  });
  
  // when a client leaves a room let us know and update
  socket.on("userLeft", room => {
    for (let i in entities) {
      console.log(" -- " + entities[i].client)
      if (entities[i].client === socket.id) {
        players[entities[i].lobby]--;
        entities.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
    console.log("Room left. ID: " + socket.id + " - Entities Left: " + entities.length + " - Room: " + room);
  });
  
  // when a client disconnects check if they are in a room
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    // check if we have a player instance and if so remove it
    for (let i in entities) {
      if (entities[i].client === socket.id) {
        players[entities[i].lobby]--;
        entities.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
    console.log("User left. ID: " + socket.id + " - Entities Left: " + entities.length)
  });
});
```

This is what I have troubleshooting:

- whenever you click the join button we'll say it logs

  ```
    join ID: aaa - Entities now: 1
  ```
- when you refresh the page right after joining (disconnect), it will log something like this:

  ```
    left ID: aaa - Entities left: 0

    left ID: bbb - Entities left: 0
  ```
- when you click the leave button, while disconnect tries *every* socket.id and eventually finds the user's, it only uses the id from the emit and will log something such as this:

  ```
    room left ID: bbb - Entities left: 1
  ```

how can I make the server keep a single id on connection, and/or fix the server creating a new connection each emit?